# Python error when trying to execute it from cmd

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd

I have installed the Microsoft store version of python and I was unable to uninstall it because I have a faulty win installation. Today I downloaded python from the official site, installed it and all was fine. I restarted my pc and now this:

```
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = 'C:\\Program Files\\Python39\\python.exe'
  sys.base_prefix = ''
  sys.base_exec_prefix = ''
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = 'C:\\Program Files\\Python39\\python.exe'
  sys.prefix = ''
  sys.exec_prefix = ''
  sys.path = [
    'C:\\Program Files\\Python39\\python39.zip',
    '.\\DLLs',
    '.\\lib',
    'C:\\Program Files\\Python39',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00005c48 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
```

what should i do?
Do i really need to make a clean windows installation

Comment: Assuming you've googled the error and tried all the solutions you could find, how come none of those worked? Please indicate here what you've found, and tried, so that we don't give you a solution that you've already tried. If you've tried nothing, then it's not appropriate to post here until you have exhausted all possible resources.

Comment: I've searched here on stack overflow, i saw a similar post of someone that had set: "PYTHONHOME , PYTHONPATH" wrong, but it was not my case since i tried what the solution for him was and didn't worked. I tried to repair and reinstall python using the installer, but nothing worked. I'm searching on google from almost 2h now. The only thing that i've not done is doing a clean windows installation.

Comment: i solved formatting my entire system and re-installing windows. Thanks guys for help <3